# Removing precompiled header files from Eclipse

Tags: c

Does anybody know how to remove this option from Eclipse? Or should I remove a piece of code from src files? What does it mean to remove the precompiled header files? I could not find it on google or gcc online docs.

I am on Windows.

/*

Actually my main problem is different than this question. But while I am searching about my main problem I saw this: [stackoverflow.com/questions/8166324/jni-unsatisfiedlinkerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166324/jni-unsatisfiedlinkerror) and if you look at the answers, he says that "My project had use precompiled headers option set, Once I removed that option it worked like magic" So I will also try to remove precompiled headers but I dont know how to do it.

Maybe this question would be helpful also to others who do not know much about precompiled header files.

*/

Comment: Can the downvoter leave a comment please? So that I can improve the question.

Comment: What you mean by precompiled header files ? Are you referring to the templates ?

Comment: Actually my main problem is different than this question. But while I am searching about my main problem I saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166324/jni-unsatisfiedlinkerror and if you look at the answers, he says that "My project had use precompiled headers option set, Once I removed that option it worked like magic" So I will also try to remove precompiled headers but I dont know how to do it.